# Reroute audio when headphones are plugged in

Tags: android, audio, media

My phone is permanently stuck in headphone mode and I want to dev an app for myself to reroute media/call audio to earpiece speaker something like SoundAbout or Audio Reroute app but for Android Oreo since thats what I have and none of those work, I'm not new to Android Studio I just don't know how to start on this project any guidance will be appreciated! I just don't want to have to revert to Nougat

Answer (score 0):

In Android, Audio policy service is responsible for all actions that require a policy decision to be made first, such as opening a new I/O audio stream, **routing** after a change, and stream volume management.

To know more details, you can refer below AOSP documentation related to audio routing and configuration.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRouting.html
https://source.android.com/devices/audio/implement-policy